moviepy installation error in GitHub Actions workflow: subprocess-exited-with-error
I'm encountering an error while trying to install moviepy in my GitHub Actions workflow. The installation works fine on my local machine, but it sometimes fails in the CI environment. The error message indicates that getting requirements to build the wheel did not run successfully, with an exit code 1. It also mentions that the error originates from a subprocess and is likely not a problem with pip.
Downloading moviepy-1.0.3.tar.gz (388 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 388.3/388.3 kB 32.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dismlhz9/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dismlhz9/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dismlhz9/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 497, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-dismlhz9/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
      NameError: name 'TestCommand' is not defined
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Notice:  A new release of pip is available: 24.1.2 -> 24.2
Notice:  To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip


My github actions file

name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - speaksmart-ai

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/

........

I have already tried upgrading pip and setuptools, but the issue persists. Here is the relevant portion of my GitHub Actions workflow file:
Setting up Python version to 3.11.
Creating and starting a virtual environment.
Installing dependencies from requirements.txt.

Facing the same issue++

Working fine on Linux env(s), Iam facing with windows

i solved by doing pip install wheeldoing first before doing pip install requirements.txt

can you pls provide the wheel URL, This is the one you are using? https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/0.2.3.4/#files ...I tried getting the same issue

I solved the issue by adding the following version to the requirements.txt
moviepy>=1.0.3

I had the exact same issue using Azure Pipelines, last successful build was 6 days ago.
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.11'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.11

    - bash: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      displayName: 'Update pip'

    - bash: |
        python -m pip install wheel
      displayName: 'Install wheel'

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt --upgrade
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

Adding python -m pip install wheel after python -m pip install --upgrade pip and before pip install requirements did the trick.



bash: |
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
displayName: 'Update pip'


bash: |
python -m pip install wheel
displayName: 'Install wheel'


bash: |
pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt --upgrade
workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
displayName: 'Install application dependencies'




Adding pip install wheel after pip upgrade and before pip install requirements did the trick.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
